# Future plans in a PhD application

Tags: phd

I intend to apply for a couple of very interesting Ph.D. positions that I am highly interested to get admitted to, however, I have a situation here. I have finished my studies in agricultural genetics in Dec 2020 and since then I applied for many Ph.D. positions and received an invitation for only one interview (my applications seems to need some improvements).

So, now I found a couple of very interesting positions in a very renowned university in my field. I took and finished some online courses in bioinformatics to strengthen my CV, and hopefully received my admissions to three summer schools this year which will end before the start of the PhD positions. The summer schools are highly related to the PhD positions and I believe that they can have a very positive effect on my applications. however, they will start next month and I am wondering how I can include them in my CV or in my motivation letter (which I feel that they may miss reading whole letters due to the high number of applications).

Can I set a new heading with "Future plans" or "Further educations" in my CV?

or Can I write them in detail in a single sheet and upload them separately on the application?

I need to mention that for the application, they only asked for a motivation letter and a CV. Although, there is a non-mandatory option to upload anything as "Others".

I would really appreciate it if you can share your experiences or ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, it's fine to note things you will complete before the start date that you won't have done by application time. They can probably fit into existing parts of your CV, just note that they are "planned" or "future" in parentheses.

Everyone who is a current student likely has at least one "planned" rather than "completed" item on their CV: finishing their current degree.

Comment: Thanks Bryan, but as I searched on the internet about this, most people offered not to include such plans in a CV because the recruiter prefers to decide based on the present or done experiences. However, I really intend to include them and hope that it won't affect negatively my application.  I just put them in the EDUCATION sector and subtitled them as a "Fixed Plan".